# How do I configure a transaction timeout in WebSphere Liberty Batch?

Tags: java, websphere-liberty, jsr352, java-batch

- What is the role of **javax.transaction.global.timeout**?
- Do I need to implement the **checkpointTimeout()** method in  **CheckpointAlgorithm**?
- Is there anything at the server config level?  How does this interact with whatever is set at the application level?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(**Edit 2016-12-02:**  Reworked with an explanation of the defaulting behavior when a timeout value of '0' is set for the application transaction).

### Overview

Let me describe the application-level options and how that interacts with the server-level timeout.

In a chunk step in WebSphere Liberty Java Batch, you can either set an application-level timeout, or set a timeout value of **'0'** to default to a server-level timeout.

In addition, you can also set an upper bound for any non-zero application-level timeout value through a separate server-level setting.

### Application-level timeout

The chunk transaction timeout can be set either:

#### In XML (static)

At the step level in JSL with special step property:  **javax.transaction.global.timeout**
(seconds)

E.g.

```
<step id="MyStep"> 
   <properties> 
      <!-- In seconds -->
      <property name="javax.transaction.global.timeout" value="120"/>
```

If not explicitly defined in XML, it defaults to 180 (seconds).

#### In Java (dynamic)

If you need more dynamic/programmatic control you can implement a custom [CheckpointAlgorithm](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/batch/api/chunk/CheckpointAlgorithm.html) and write its [checkpointTimeout()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/batch/api/chunk/CheckpointAlgorithm.html#checkpointTimeout) to return whatever you want (a different value for each chunk even if you really wanted).

### Server(JVM)-level timeouts

#### Setting an upper bound for application timeout values

You can prevent the application from setting too great a timeout value.

In the server config (server.xml) use **propogatedOrBMTTranLifetimeTimeout** :

```
<transaction propogatedOrBMTTranLifetimeTimeout="90s"/>
```

This will act as an upper bound on any *non-zero* application timeout value, either via `javax.transaction.global.timeout` or your **checkpointTimeout()** method,

#### Default timeout when application timeout is not set

In the case that the `javax.transaction.global.timeout` is set to **'0'** or the case that your **checkpointTimeout()** method returns **'0'**, you will get a default timeout from the server.

This timeout value defaults to 120 seconds.

To change in the server config (server.xml) use **totalTranLifetimeTimeout**, e.g.:

```
<transaction totalTranLifetimeTimeout="60s"/>
```

#### Note:

As mentioned above, though, if `javax.transaction.global.timeout` isn't set at all the  application timeout defaults to 180, and so the **totalTranLifetimeTimeout** does **NOT** come into play.

### Other notes / references

**Note:** the [WDT](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/) tool's *Design View* makes working with and remembering these server config attribute values much easier.

#### Mapping to WebSphere Application Server traditional config

The *propogatedOrBMTTranLifetimeTimeout* attribute here basically maps to the **Maximum transaction timeout** in traditional, while the *totalTranLifetimeTimeout* maps more obviously the **Total transaction lifetime timeout** in traditional.

Some nice examples are described within [this documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/udat_contranserv.html) which are still largely relevant in Liberty.